# How to write these two symbols in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

How to write these two symbols in LaTeX

[image]

I know the Latex symbols are $\Delta$ but how to shade the Delta in Latex?
Please help.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471441/134144 might be helpful.

Comment: Also, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \(\color{red}\blacktriangle\)
        \item \(\color{red}\blacktriangledown\)
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

That would give you

[image: A picture of the output that the given source code produces.]

Comment: Thanks a lot, great solution

Comment: This would look great on an elevator.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution for LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\newcommand\redtriangleup{\textcolor{Red}{\bigblacktriangleup}}
\newcommand\redtriangledown{\textcolor{Red}{\bigblacktriangledown}}

\begin{document}
\[ \redtriangleup\redtriangledown \]
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern sample]

In PDFTeX, load `\usepackage{stix}` or `\usepackage{stix2}` instead of `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}`.

**ETA:** You can replace `\bigblacktriangleup` with `\blacktriangleup` and `\bigblacktriangledown` with `\blacktriangledown` as in needle’s answer, while using the same approach.  Many more packages support these commands.